# Change background color to navbar in bootstrap-vuejs

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

According with the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/navbar/), the styles for the navigation bar can be set as follows:

```
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="info">
<!-- Or -->
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="dark">
```

Anyway, just by changing the `type` and `variant` props. I want however to set a custom background color like `#AABB55`. I cannot find an easy way to do it.

Furthermore, when you see the documentation and the [source code](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/navbar/navbar.js), you don't have many options.

Is there a way to change this property without needing to touch the `<b-navbar>` code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Damn. I finished the question and I solved it just after.

So, let's say that I have inside the template

```
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="dark">
  <!-- more stuff -->
</b-navbar>
```

Then in the style you can just add:

```
<style scoped>
 .navbar.navbar-dark.bg-dark{
    background-color: #AABB55!important;
 }
</style>
```

Note: without `!important` it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: It doesn't work without `!important` because CSS follows specificity to work out which rule to apply, your rule in theory is not the right one for CSS to apply but with the important flag you raise the specificity calculation for that rule.

Comment: With scoped styles, you need to use the `/deep/` selector to target inner elements of a child component.  https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements